# setting cors header for chromecast

Tags: android, chromecast

How do I set the CORS headers for M3U8 file streaming in Chromecast? In my sender (Android) I am setting the Metadata and MediaInfo like this:

```
metaData = new MediaMetadata(MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MOVIE);
metaData.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE, "Demo Video");

MediaInfo mediaInfo = new MediaInfo.Builder(
        "http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/bbbfull/bbbfull.m3u8")
        .setContentType("application/vnd.apple.mpegurl")
        .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED)
        .setMetadata(metaData)
        .build();

player.load(client, mediaInfo, true)
      .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<RemoteMediaPlayer.MediaChannelResult>() {
       @Override
       public void onResult(RemoteMediaPlayer.MediaChannelResult mediaChannelResult) {
                    Status status = mediaChannelResult.getStatus();
                                 if (status.isSuccess()) {
                                  }
                                  }
                                  });
```

My onLoad method is set up like this:

```
mediaManager.onLoad = function(event) {
        console.log("### Media Manager - LOAD: " + JSON.stringify(event));

        if(mediaPlayer !== null) {
            mediaPlayer.unload(); // Ensure unload before loading again
        }

        if (event.data['media'] && event.data['media']['contentId']) {
            var url = event.data['media']['contentId'];

            mediaHost = new cast.player.api.Host({
                'mediaElement': mediaElement,
                'url': url
            });

            mediaHost.onError = function (errorCode) {
                console.error('### HOST ERROR - Fatal Error: code = ' + errorCode);

                if (mediaPlayer !== null) {
                    mediaPlayer.unload();
                }
            }

            var initialTimeIndexSeconds = event.data['media']['currentTime'] || 0;
            // TODO: real code would know what content it was going to access and this would not be here.
            var protocol = null;

            var parser = document.createElement('a');
            parser.href = url;

            var ext = ext = parser.pathname.split('.').pop();
            if (ext === 'm3u8') {
                protocol =  cast.player.api.CreateHlsStreamingProtocol(mediaHost);
            } else if (ext === 'mpd') {
                protocol = cast.player.api.CreateDashStreamingProtocol(mediaHost);
            } else if (ext === 'ism/') {
                protocol = cast.player.api.CreateSmoothStreamingProtocol(mediaHost);
            }
            console.log('### Media Protocol Identified as ' + ext);


            if (protocol === null) {

                mediaManager['onLoadOrig'](event); // Call on the original callback
            } else {

                mediaPlayer = new cast.player.api.Player(mediaHost);
                mediaPlayer.load(protocol, initialTimeIndexSeconds);
            }
        }
    }
```

However,  I am getting this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/bbbfull/bbbfull.m3u8. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '----' is therefore not allowed access.
```

For Chromecast, how do I set the CORS headers for Chromecast?

Comment: You have to enable the web server that hosts the media content:
https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/player#cors

Answer (score 1):

Probably too late, but just came across with the same issue and get it done by the approach mentioned below.

I didn't get a way to add headers on sender app side so, sharing my own experience. I get the CORS issue fixed upon firstly confirming that my server is supporting CORS. And then for playing the media on chromecast, i was needed to add **gstatic.com and in my case another one as well** as allowed domains on server, which is in-fact the whole idea of CORS, that each domain should be known to our server. And that's it.

Note: Be very much sure to [go through this official documentation.](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/receiver_apps) But for being a beginner it may appear a bit tricky to grab all the stuff from here. So shared own experience as well.

Comment: hello can you please elaborate about "add gstatic.com "  also can you please check this issue https://github.com/googlecast/CastReceiver/issues/26

Comment: You need to whitelist chromecast origin i.e. gstatic on your Server so that stream can be received when requested from chromecast.